# How to using the loop and bulk load tasks to insert the name of the csv files being looped?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Description

- I have created an SSIS package imports data from hundreds of csv files on a daily bases
- I have used the bulk load and foreach loop container

Problem

- I have created a column on a database table and wanted to know if it is possible to add the source file name on each row of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the filename in a variable (which you could do in the for each loop) then you just use the variable as the data source for the column. Or ther may be a system variable that contains the file name, pole around a bit inthe system varaibles available to you and see.